# Django: atomic(): Force transaction, raise AssertionError if already inside a transaction

Tags: python, django, database, transactions

I have a problem with `atomic()` in Django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

For some methods (called outside request/response cycle) I need to be sure, that the method is executed in one transaction. I must force durability. `atomic()` would silently use a savepoints if already inside a transaction.

Remember: ACID http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

- Atomicity
- Consistency
- Isolation
- Durability <--- That what I want to force.

The keyword argument `savepoint` for `atomic()` does not help here. If you use savepoint=False `atomic()` does silently nothing (according to the docs) if already inside a transaction.

I need an Exception if the is already a transaction running.

Unfortunately the old `is_managed()` is deprecated without a replacement.

How can I create a `atomic_raise_exception_if_already_in_transaction()` decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use only the `atomic()` then you can check for `in_atomic_block` property of the connection:

```
>>> from django.db import transaction
>>> transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block
False
>>> with transaction.atomic():
...     print transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block
... 
True
>>> transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Detecting whether there is a transaction running on your DB connection depends on the behaviour of your db backend library. E.g. `psycopg2` for postgresql does implicitly start a new transaction when submitting a new query when previous transaction has been finished unless explicit autocommit mode has been turned on. In the former case, all queries will run inside a transaction thus leaving you with no reliable checks other than commiting current transaction.

You can, on the other hand, detect whether there is an `atomic` block active, see [docs](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/db/transaction.py#L256). You can use the `connection.in_atomic_block` property to check whether there has been any `atomic` block activated.